# How to estimate an additive hazards model?

Tags: estimation, survival, hazard, proportional-hazards

Consider the [additive hazards model](https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article/81/1/61/252141/Semiparametric-analysis-of-the-additive-risk-model):

$$\lambda(t) = \lambda_0(t) + \beta^T Z.$$

I want to assume that the baseline hazard $\lambda_0(t) $ is Weibull. However, $\lambda(t)$ has to be positive by definition, thus $\lambda_0(t) \geq - \beta^T Z$. How can I impose such conditions in practice?

Comment: What is your motivation for this constraint?

Answer (score 0):

The paper you linked to has the answer in the conclusions. It says

"One may avoid the constraint for the additive risk model by substituting $e^{\beta^T Z}$ for $\beta^T Z$."

So, that restriction is not needed.